# Performance measures of PyTorch / Skorch NN are all zero

Tags: python, pytorch, neural-network, regression, skorch

I am trying the predict prices and I used PyTorch and Skorch to build a neural network for the predictions. I found this helpful article that shows how to do it for classification: [https://towardsdatascience.com/pycaret-skorch-build-pytorch-neural-networks-using-minimal-code-57079e197f33#:~:text=Yes%2C%20you%20heard%20it%20right,which%20is%20what%20PyCaret%20expects!](https://towardsdatascience.com/pycaret-skorch-build-pytorch-neural-networks-using-minimal-code-57079e197f33#:%7E:text=Yes%2C%20you%20heard%20it%20right,which%20is%20what%20PyCaret%20expects!). I changed the code such that it now runs for regression. However, the performance measures all output zero. Can someone help me out?

This is the code I currently have:

```
`from skorch import NeuralNetRegressor
from skorch.helper import DataFrameTransformer
from skorch.callbacks import EarlyStopping

target = "Price"

exp = setup(data = train, 
             test_data = test,
             target = target)

class RegressorModule(nn.Module):
    def __init__(
            self,
            input_size= 13,
            num_units=150,
            num_units_d1=100,
            num_units_d2=50,
            nonlin=F.relu,
    ):
        super(RegressorModule, self).__init__()
        self.num_units = num_units
        self.nonlin = nonlin

        self.dense0 = nn.LazyLinear(input_size, num_units)
        self.dense1 = nn.LazyLinear(num_units, num_units_d1)
        self.dense2 = nn.LazyLinear(num_units_d1, num_units_d2)
        self.output = nn.LazyLinear(num_units_d2, 1)

    def forward(self, X, **kwargs):
        X = self.nonlin(self.dense0(X))
        X = self.nonlin(self.dense1(X))
        X = self.nonlin(self.dense2(X))
        X = self.output(X)
        return X
    
    def training_step(self, batch, **kwargs):
        data, target = batch
        predictions = self.forward(data)
        loss = F.mse_loss(predictions, target)
        rmse = torch.sqrt(loss)
        self.log('train_rmse', rmse, on_step=True, on_epoch=True, prog_bar=True)
        return loss

class MyNet(NeuralNetRegressor):
    def fit(self, X, y):
        if y.ndim == 1:
            y = y.values.reshape(-1, 1)
        return super().fit(X, y)

net_regr = MyNet(
    module=RegressorModule(input_size=13),
    max_epochs=20,
    lr=0.1,
    train_split=None,
)

nn_pipe = Pipeline(
    [
        ("transform", DataFrameTransformer()),
        ("net", net_regr),
    ]
)
skorch_model = exp.create_model(nn_pipe)`
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rqUaH.png)

and this image shows the output.

Comment: Please refrain from posting output as images. See [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors)

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand the example code correctly. Where does log come from and why is training step defined on the torch module? What are the metrics during training? Are they zero as well?